# Unable to download .zip file from content version

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

One of my colleague uploaded .zip files as content version in his org, and he shared me the file via public link. But, when I try to download the file, it's just navigating me to an empty tab in chrome browser and nothing is happening after that. I am not seeing any error and the file also not getting downloaded. I couldn't figure out the issue. If some faced anything similar like this kindly provide your solution. [image]